# addEventListener("load",...) causing too many XmlHttpRequests?

Tags: javascript, apache, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon

Suppose I have the following JavaScript code running in a Firefox plugin, which should perform an `XmlHttpRequest` on a page load:

```
function my_fun(){

var xmlHttpConnection = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpConnection.open('GET', globalUrl+'/call_this.php', true);
    xmlHttpConnection.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlHttpConnection.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpConnection.status == 200) {
            var serverResponse = xmlHttpConnection.responseText;
            do_stuff();
            clearTimeout(xmlHttpTimeout);
            xmlHttpConnection.abort();
       }
 };

 xmlHttpConnection.send(null);
 xmlHttpTimeout = setTimeout(function (){
                                 do_other_stuff();
                                 xmlHttpConnection.abort();
                                 clearTimeout(xmlHttpTimeout);
                             },5000);
}

container.addEventListener("load", my_fun, true);
```

When `my_fun()` is called, the access logs for my Apache server look something like this:

```
<client-ip> - - [06/Nov/2014:10:40:04 -0500] "GET /call_this.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

Further suppose I have 4 client connections on my server.  Within the span 1 second, this line can show up in the access log dozens (sometimes over 50) of times simultaneously, and the pings sometimes come from just 1 client. Most times, the number of pings per second is lower than 5, but  there are occasional spikes caused by `call_this.php`.

Why would this happen?  I suspect something is wrong with `container.addEventListener("load", my_fun, true);`.  Does this over count the number of loads, e.g., if a page contains multiple hidden URL's that are loaded?  If so, how can I fix this? (Edit: Would an observer service be better?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  I do believe there is a problem with the event listener.  But since the above code is in a Firefox plugin, a good approach is to use Mozilla observers.  The following observer significantly reduced the number of pings to the server (empirically tested).

Special thanks goes to Noitidart, who supplied a similar solution to a different problem.

```
var myObserver = {
register: function() {
    var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
    observerService.addObserver(this, TOPIC_MODIFY_REQUEST, false);
},
    //observe function to capture the changed event
    observe : function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
        if (TOPIC_MODIFY_REQUEST == aTopic ) {
            var url;
            aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);

            url = aSubject.URI.spec;
            url = encodeURIComponent(url);

            var oHttp = aSubject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
            if (oHttp.loadFlags & Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel.LOAD_INITIAL_DOCUMENT_URI) {
                //is top level load
                my_fun(); //Same function as in original question
            }
        }
    }       
} 

myObserver.register();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. something looks wrong to me:

Check this line:

```
container.addEventListener("load", function(){my_fun();}, true);
```

or change function declaration:

```
function my_fun(){
...
```

for

```
my_fun = function(){
...
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve my problem.  Won't the event listener still be triggered the same number of times, hence the same problem will arise?

Comment: then, all I can guess is that something may be causing load event trigger many times. Does the response do something with the container? Maybe using console.log("xxxx")  inside your function will shed some light on it.